# Handling Multiple read and Single writes

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, shared-memory

I am very new to this topic. Its confusing whenever I try to get one process done after another, The next process kicks in before executing the first process.

For example : I am reading from the shared memory , I want the next **write** process wait until the **read** is over. But after reading some portion the write process comes in and changes the values.

I have tried to code using mutex and cond_wait. Maybe there are some errors or I  dont know really how cond_wait works properly. Need help

my code snippet:

```
void create_reader()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (0 == fork()) {
        reader();
        exit(0);
    }
    readerID++;
    r+=1;

    pthread_cond_signal(&condition);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void create_writer()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    while (!r)
    {
        cout<<"waiting"<<endl;
        pthread_cond_wait(&condition,&mutex);
    }

    if (0 == fork()) {
        writer();
        exit(0);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    writerID++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `fork()` will create a copy of the running process, if the writer change the memory in the second process, the reader will never see the memory modification in its own:

- threads share memory
- processes don't (unless you share memory with `mmap`)

That said, your other pthread functions calls seem correct.

See http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them

Comment: it is mmap that I used, but the writer doesnt wait until the read is done. Thats what I am getting wrong